# Update data automatically while selecting it

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to get the data:

```
$resultsTicket = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM orders_history 
     WHERE customer_name = '$member_name' 
     AND order_method = 'EStock'
     ORDER BY id ASC");
```

And here is the result:

**orders_history**

```
----------------------------
  unique_random    quantity       
----------------------------
  12C3EDsE34e        5      
  sad234sadsa        7
```

From the result above, in the view page, the user will choose how many quantity they want to choose. For example, in the first row: they choose 3 from 5 quantity. And when it is submitted, the data will be post to another table:

**claim_history**

```
----------------------------
  unique_random    claim       
----------------------------
  12C3EDsE34e        3      
  sad234sadsa        2
```

My question now is how to update the quantity in the first table (orders_history) automatically.

**orders_history**

```
----------------------------
  unique_random    quantity       
----------------------------
  12C3EDsE34e        2      
  sad234sadsa        5
```

I have tried it like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
                            <?php
                            $customer_email=$member_email;          

                            $resultsTicket = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM orders_history 
                                                             WHERE customer_name = '$member_name' 
                                                             AND order_method = 'EStock'
                                                             ORDER BY id ASC");

                                             $mysqli->query ("UPDATE orders_history
                                                             LEFT JOIN estockClaims on estockClaims.transaction_id = orders_history.transaction_id
                                                             SET orders_history.quantity = orders_history.quantity - estockClaims.quantity;
                                                             ");
                                if ($resultsTicket > 0) {
                                    $i = 0; 
                                    $random = substr(str_shuffle(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ),0, 1) . substr(str_shuffle(aBcEeFgHiJkLmNoPqRstUvWxYz0123456789),0, 6);
                                    while($obj = $resultsTicket->fetch_object()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

After successful insertion in claim_history you can us update sql such as:

```
$mysqli->query("update orders_history set quantity = quantity - selectedQuantity where unique_random=your selected value");
```

// since you will have two or more items so write it inside a loop.

if you want to achieve that: better write some onchage event,trigger it from view on each select and update the table accordingly.

But i think you should not update the table at the time of select better update it after inserting in second table otherwise you have to deal with some more problems.

Comment: My question is how select it and update it at the same time with this code: `$resultsTicket = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM orders_history 
                                                             WHERE customer_name = '$member_name' 
                                                             AND order_method = 'EStock'
                                                             ORDER BY id ASC");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an on  update trigger in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html

- Avoid sql injection by escaping your variables.

Comment: Can you help me with the update code above. I have tried it but it doesn't seem to work. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Along with posting the data to `claim_history` table, you may run an update query:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE orders_history SET quantity = ".$newQuantity." WHERE unique_random = " . $uniqueRandom);
```

Comment: how to select it and update it at the same time with this code: `$resultsTicket = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM orders_history WHERE customer_name = '$member_name' AND order_method = 'EStock' ORDER BY id ASC");`

Comment: what do you mean by new quantity here.

Comment: @suchit `$newQuantity` is to be determined on developer's preferences. Yes, it's obvious it's  `quantity - selectedQuantity`, but I rather put it in explicit variable.

Comment: so it is same what i have given but he is asking for something else.

Comment: @klaudia I believe it's not possible. Why do you have a problem running two queries one after another?

Comment: I have tried it with different queries but it doesn't seem to work. Please have a look at my code above.